# Eclipse argument input by command line

Tags: java, eclipse, console, command-line-arguments

Is there any way of using the console as command line in Eclipse, instead of setting the arguments every single time in preferences? I'm coding in java, and using multiple Scanners, it doesn't show the input given and I'd like to see it, and by giving the arguments in the console I could also test my exceptions. Thanks for help.

Comment: You could write a program that prompts the user for input, splits the result (on space), uses `Class.forName` to find the class identified by the first word, then runs its main method, passing the remaining arguments.  It would be difficult to make it handle every possible case (such as quoted arguments containing space), but probably quite easy to create one that's good enough for your purposes.  Or you could just use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec( ... )`.

Comment: Short answer is you can't pass Android arguments through the command line.